# Mergin overlapped intervals from set of ranges

Tags: python

Supposed we have a list of intervals:
Then we need to find all overlapped intervals based on above intervals.

```
inputs = [[1,4], [2,5], [7,10], [12,14], [15,19]]
output = [[1,5], [7,10], [12,14], [15,19]]
```

Seems my code didn't work:

```
merged = []
start, end = inputs[0]

for i, [t1, t2] in enumerate(inputs):
    if end <= t2:
        if start <= inputs[i+1][0]:
            end = t2
            merged.append([start, end])
```

Comment: Are you sure about the desired output? Aren't [1,4] and [2,11] supposed to give you [1,11] (which also covers [2,5] and [7,10])?

Comment: Oh you were right, let me fix it first

Comment: `input` is a builtin in Python, don't shadow it by overwriting it.

Comment: i use notepad.exe to build and didn't realize that, thanks

Comment: Your code only assigns `start, end = inputs[0]` so it only considers the 0'th interval for merging with the others. But the 0'th interval might be disjoint. So you need to walk `start, end` along the whole list `inputs[i]`. It might be better to have two loops, i and j, to walk along `inputs[i]` and `inputs[j]` for i<j. You should add another testcase that exercises that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you process the intervals in ascending order according to the left end, and each time extend the last added interval (if needed), in case the next interval intersects it, or add a new interval to the list, in case it doesn't, it should work, I think.

Here's the code:

```
inputs = [[2,5], [1,4], [7,10], [12,14], [15,19]]
inputs.sort()

outputs = [inputs[0]]
for interval in inputs[1:]:
    if outputs[-1][1] >= interval[0]: # intersection
        outputs[-1][1] = max(outputs[-1][1], interval[1])
    else: # no intersection
        outputs.append(interval)

print(outputs)
```